# Remove committer information from git commits

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-filter-branch

I have rebased a branch and now all its commits have committer section which I would like to remove completely (not just changing it's fields). Is it possible without losing the original author info?

Comment: Every commit have a committer header as well as an author header. You may see only one of them when both are identical with some clients, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to **@sergej** and **GitHub**, I got committer info removed with

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" != "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" ]; then
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to rewrite the history.

GitHub has a script that does that, see [Changing author info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/).

It should be straight forward to adopt it to your needs:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand correctly, that if `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` etc match `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` etc, it will be considered as removed?

Comment: Yeah, just tested, seems to be the case

Comment: doesn't work. Creates another branch with the old wrong commits.

Comment: @LiquidCore have you down-voted this answer? It might not work for [you question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50583090/2020827), but it helped here.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone confused by this exchange, Liquidcore is upset because the answer didn't point out that `filter-branch` creates back up refs, and this confused them into thinking the command hand't worked.  Rather than admit to having been in error, they appear to have doubled down by standing behind an inappropriate down-vote, when in fact the answer worked fine.