# How to easily examine empty commits on a git branch from some point on?

Tags: git, automation, git-commit

I suspect I may have a commit on a branch of mine - after the branch point from a master branch - which is empty. I want to find this commit (or maybe more than one?) and have a look at its commit message

Now, I could of course examine all commits from the branch point one by one and check whether they're empty or not. I could probably even write a shell script which takes the number of commits to look back and keeps executing

```
git diff HEAD^{n+1}  HEAD^^^^...lots of ^{n}
```

and checking the number of output lines, and using that to get the commit IDs. But - I was hoping there was some either way to better automate this. I know that there's a `git filter-branch` command which could *remove* empty commits, but I first want to know whether I had any and where they are. Also I don't want to go all the way back to the initial commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find empty git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683792/how-can-i-find-empty-git-commits)

Comment: @Serge: I've tweaked my question to be different than that one. Also note I don't want to go all the way back to the initial commit.

Comment: you can easily modify the scripts in the answer to use revieion ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
git log --stat
```

which will give you, for every commit listing, a line such as:

```
7 files changed, 55 insertions(+), 75 deletions(-)
```

then you can search for `0 files changed`. Now, that isn't full automation, but since you said you wanted to have a look at which commits these are, that's a good way to do it.

You could also use something like

```
sed -r '/^commit [a-z]{8,}/,/^[1-9] files changed/d'
```

on the log output, to remove the entries for commits with changes. (Caveat: haven't tested this sed command.)